# Set fixed height of rows in select ouput

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I use MySQL Workbench 6.2.4. When I make a `select` query for columns that contain, for example, html code, workbench makes the resulting rows very high. Some rows are of normal height, but some are too high. It's very difficult to work with such rows. Is it possible to make all rows with the same fixed height?

This is the image (I hid text with black color)
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, so we get an idea what exactly does it look like?

Comment: @Mike Lischke I added screenshot.

Comment: Ugh, that sshot doesn't tell me much. Where is that taken from? I don't see context. And btw, always use the latest WB release (6.2.4 at the time of writing this with 6.2.5 around the corner).

Comment: @Mike Lischke I thinkg you don't understand the question. Shortly - I do select in mysql workbench. Workbench shows me the data from DB. The problem is that rows in this output have different heights. The output screenshot I've posted. That's all.

Comment: Strange, I can't replicate this. I think Mike is wanting to see context in terms of seeing the related Workbench panels as there might be something else going on. In any case, this is not expected behavior, so it feels like a potential bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Workbench expands the height of a row if it is not able to display the data within a column due to the data length being on the higher side.

If you wish to see uniform rows, then there is a parameter called "Max.Field Value length to display (in bytes)" in Edit>Preferences>SQL Queries tab which can be modified.
This value indicates the max length of each column to be displayed.

Suggest you reduce it to a small length & run the query again.

ps : check the screenshot.
[image: MySQL Workbench]

Comment: But why other rows are shorted and ended with "..."?

Comment: Any column data which exceeds the specific limit will be visible as "..."